# Delete void* in C++11 using type erasure

Tags: c++, c++11, type-erasure

I'm trying to fix a ***double free or corruption*** in this class:

```
struct Holder
{
    template <typename T>
    Holder(const T& v)
    {
        _v = new T{};
        memcpy(_v, &v, sizeof(T));

        _deleter = [this]{
            if (_v != nullptr)
            {
                delete reinterpret_cast<T*>(_v);
                _v = nullptr;
            }
        };
    }

    template <typename T>
    T get()
    {
        T t;
        memcpy(&t, _v, sizeof(T));
        return t;
    }

    ~Holder()
    {
        std::cout << "~Holder() " << std::endl;
        _deleter();
    }

private:
    void* _v;
    std::function<void()> _deleter;
};
```

The goal of this class is to Hold a value of a particular type, like `boost::any`. So I'm trying to understand the mechanism to safely deallocate all memory.

Probably this line of code:

```
delete reinterpret_cast<T*>(_v);
```

doesn't do what I expect ...

******** After Suggestions ********

I've rewrite the code using comment suggestions and adding a **move constructor**

```
struct Holder
{
    template <typename T>
    Holder(const T& v)
    {
        std::cerr << "create " << N << std::endl;
        _v = new T(v);

        _deleter = [this]{
            if (_v != nullptr)
            {
                std::cerr << "deleter " << N << std::endl;
                delete reinterpret_cast<T*>(_v);
                _v = nullptr;
            }
        };
    }


    Holder(Holder&& rs)
    {
        _v = rs._v;
        _deleter = std::move(rs._deleter);
        rs._deleter = []{}; //usefull to avoid a bad function call
    }


    template <typename T>
    T get() const
    {
        return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(_v);
    }

    ~Holder()
    {
        //std::cout << "~Holder() " << N << std::endl;
        _deleter();
    }

private:
    void* _v;
    std::function<void()> _deleter;
};
```

Now seems work but I have to manage others corner case :)
Probably the best solution is to use **boost::any**:

```
struct Holder
{
    template <typename T>
    Holder(const T& v)
    {
        _v = v;
    }

    template <typename T>
    T get()
    {
        return boost::any_cast<T>(_v);
    }

private:
    boost::any _v;
};
```

But I'am trying to understand how it coudl works without it.

This is my last version:

```
struct Holder
{
    template <typename T>
    Holder(const T& v)
    {
        std::cerr << "create " << N << std::endl;
        _v = new T(v);

        _deleter = [](void* ptr){
            if (ptr != nullptr)
            {
                std::cerr << "deleter " << std::endl;
                delete reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr);
            }
        };

        _builder = [](void* &dest, void* src){
            dest = new T(*reinterpret_cast<T*>(src));
        };
    }

    Holder(const Holder& rs)
    {
        std::cerr << "copy constr" << std::endl;
        if (this != &rs)
        {
            rs._builder(_v, rs._v);
            _deleter = rs._deleter;
            _builder = rs._builder;
        }
    }

    Holder(Holder&& rs)
    {
        std::cerr << "move constr" << std::endl;
        if (this != &rs)
        {
            _v = rs._v;
            _deleter = std::move(rs._deleter);
            _builder = std::move(rs._builder);
            rs._deleter = [](void*){};
        }
    }

    Holder& operator=(const Holder& rs)
    {
        std::cerr << "copy operator" << std::endl;
        if (this != &rs)
        {
            rs._builder(_v, rs._v);
            _deleter = rs._deleter;
            _builder = rs._builder;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    Holder& operator=(Holder&& rs)
    {
        std::cerr << "move operator" << std::endl;
        if (this != &rs)
        {
            _v = rs._v;
            _deleter = std::move(rs._deleter);
            _builder = std::move(rs._builder);
            rs._deleter = [](void*){};
        }

        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T>
    T get() const
    {
        return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(_v);
    }

    ~Holder()
    {
        //std::cout << "~Holder() " << N << std::endl;
        _deleter(_v);
    }

private:
    void* _v;
    std::function<void(void* ptr)> _deleter;
    std::function<void(void* &, void* src)> _builder;
};
```

Comment: You should probably be following [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28computer_programming%29).

Comment: ANd that `memcpy` is also a no-go.

Comment: Why not use placement-new? Aka `_v = new char[sizeof(T)]; new (_v) T(v);` And why calling the default constructor everywhere? Ie, `T const& get() const { return reinterpret_cast<T const&>(_v); }` seems to make more sense to me.

Comment: thanks Carlo yes I agree is more readeable

Comment: @CarloWood: why using intermediate buffer ? Why not directly `_v = new T(v);`

Comment: Note that this way Holder is non-copyable (or should be), which is probably not what you want. To make a long story short, I think you delete it all and start from scratch, rethinking what you really want.

Comment: @Jarod42 : lol - yes you're right. Can you imagine how confusing the original code was ;)

Comment: So it looks like you're trying for something with the per-object deleter features of `std::shared_ptr`, but the single owner semantics of `std::unique_ptr` ?  Actually, `std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void()>` should provide that combination.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reimplement the horse.

```
using pvoid_holder = std::unique_ptr<void, std::function<void(void*)>>
template<class T>
pvoid_holder pvoid_it( T* t ) {
  return { t, [](void* v){ if (v) delete static_cast<T*>(v); } };
}
```

Now store a `pvoid_holder` in your `Holder` class.  It will handle memory lifetime for you.

You could use a naked `pvoid_holder`, but it might have a richer interface than you want (for example, it will allow the stored pointer to be changed without changing the deleter).

You can also replace `std::function` with `void(*)(void*)` for a marginal performance gain.

Comment: Note that the `if` may be redundant, but I did not want to look up if `reinterpret_cast` on `(void*)0` had any quirks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a random idea. I still don't like it though. The whole idea behind this design is bad.

```
template <typename T>
struct Holder
{
  public:
    Holder(T const& v)
    {
      new (&m_v) T(v);
    }

    T const& get() const
    {
      return reinterpret_cast<T const&>(m_v);
    }

    T& get()
    {
      return reinterpret_cast<T&>(m_v);
    }

    ~Holder()
    {
      std::cout << "~Holder() " << std::endl;
      get().~T();
    }

  private:
    char m_v[sizeof(T)];
};
```

This class doesn't do the same as yours anymore, ie it can't store arbitrary types in a `std::vector<Holder>` but only the same type (`std::vector<Holder<Foo>>`). A comment was too small to contain this code though and I wanted to show a better looking syntax for what you're playing with ;).

That being said, the only way you can do what you're trying to do is when you add a second layer for the reference counting. Ie, you replace your `void* _v` with something that resembles `shared_ptr` but which doesn't call delete when the count reaches zero but calls deleter (which therefore should be stored inside this new class). In fact your class looks mostly like this new class, except that you should make it non-copyable and provide reference counting (ie through `boost::intrusive_ptr`). Then `Holder` can be a wrapper around that that is copyable.

Comment: is not the same ... Holder now dependend on T.

Answer (score 0):

*Probably this line of code:*  `delete reinterpret_cast<T*>(_v);`  *doesn't do what I expect ...*

Not exactly.  Your types are likely using a default copy ctor; this copies your data pointer `_v`, and your deleter.  So when both objects destruct, both deleters trigger, causing the data to be deleted twice.  (Side note--you shouldn't name variables starting with `_`; such identifiers are reserved for implementations).

Here's what it takes to do type erasure properly, assuming I've no bugs in it.  A better way would be to stick to using boost::any.

```
#include <utility>
struct EmptyType {}; // Thrown if unexpectedly empty
struct InvalidType {}; // Thrown if Holder(T) but get<U>.
struct Holder
{
   Holder()
      : data_()
      , deleter_(e_deleter)
      , copier_(e_copier)
      , typetag_()
   {
   }
   template<typename T>
      Holder(const T& t)
         : data_(erase_cast(new T))
         , deleter_(deleter<T>)
         // Need to explicitly carry T's copy behavior
         // because Holder's default copy ctor isn't going to
         , copier_(copier<T>)
         // You need some way to protect against getting
         // an Orange out of a Holder that holds an Apple.
         , typetag_(id<T>())
      {
      }
   Holder(const Holder& rhs)
      : data_(rhs.copy())
      , deleter_(rhs.deleter_)
      , copier_(rhs.copier_)
      , typetag_(rhs.typetag_)
   {
   }
   template<typename T>
      T get()
      {
         if (!data_) throw EmptyType();
         T rv(fetch<T>());
         return rv;
      }
   Holder(Holder&& rhs)
      : data_()
      , copier_(rhs.copier_)
      , deleter_(rhs.deleter_)
      , typetag_(rhs.typetag_)
   {
      std::swap(data_, rhs.data_);
   }
   ~Holder()
   {
      destroy();
   }
private:
   // Reinterpret_cast wrappers labeled semantically
   template<typename T>
      static void* erase_cast(T* t) { return reinterpret_cast<void*>(t); }
   template<typename T>
      static T* unerase_cast(void* t) { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(t); }
   // Return a data copy
   void* copy() const { return copier_(data_); }
   // Return const reference to data
   template<typename T>
      const T& fetch() {
         if (typetag_!=id<T>()) throw InvalidType();
         return *unerase_cast<T>(data_);
      }
   // Destroy data
   void destroy() { deleter_(data_); data_=0; }

   // ==== Type erased copy semantics ===
   void*(*copier_)(void*);
   template<typename T>
      static void* copier(void* v) {
         return erase_cast<T>(new T(*unerase_cast<T>(v)));
      }
   static void* e_copier(void*) { return 0; }

   // ==== Type erased delete semantics ===
   void(*deleter_)(void*);
   template<typename T>
      static void deleter(void* v) {
         delete unerase_cast<T>(v);
      }
   static void e_deleter(void*) {}

   // ==== Type protection using tagging (could also use typeid)
   static int makenewid() { static int i=0; return i++;}
   template<typename T>
      static int id() { static int i=makenewid(); return i; }
   // Type erased data
   void* data_;
   // Type erased tag
   int typetag_;
};
```

...and here is some test/demo code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#define FAIL() std::cout << "Fail" << std::endl; return 1
int foos=0;
struct Foo { Foo(){++foos;} Foo(const Foo&){++foos;} ~Foo(){--foos;} };
int bars=0;
struct Bar { Bar(){++bars;} Bar(const Bar&){++bars;} ~Bar(){--bars;} };

int main() {
   {
      std::vector<Holder> v;
      Foo fx,fy,fz; Bar ba,bb;
      v.push_back(fx); v.push_back(fy); v.push_back(fz);
      v.push_back(ba); v.push_back(ba); v.push_back(bb);
      v.push_back(Holder());
      try {
         Foo y = v[2].get<Foo>();
      }
      catch (EmptyType&) { FAIL(); }
      catch (InvalidType&) { FAIL(); }
      try {
         Foo y = v[4].get<Foo>();
         FAIL();
      }
      catch (EmptyType&) { FAIL(); }
      catch (InvalidType&) { }
      try {
         Foo y = v[6].get<Foo>();
         FAIL();
      }
      catch (EmptyType&) {  }
      catch (InvalidType&) { FAIL(); }
   }
   if (foos||bars) { FAIL(); }
   std::cout << "Pass" << std::endl;
}
```

Test results:

```
$ ./a.exe
Pass
```